# Linking a js file to html for a floating button in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a floating top button in Dreamweaver. As it will be used on many pages, I want the script to be in a separate .js file. I am admittedly a complete amateur and this is my first time using javascript.

HTML code includes:

```
<link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="TopBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

My common.css file includes:

```
#TopBtn {
display: none; 
position: fixed;
bottom: 1.25em;
right: 1.5em;
z-index: 99;font-size: 1em;
border: none;
outline: none;
background-color: #555;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 1em;
border-radius: .5em;
opacity: 0.5;
}

#TopBtn:hover {
background-color: #555;
opacity: 1;
}
```

and my common.js file includes:

```
//Get the button
            var mybutton = document.getElementById("TopBtn");

            // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
            window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

            function scrollFunction() {
                if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                mybutton.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                mybutton.style.display = "none";
}
            }

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
            function topFunction() {
                document.body.scrollTop = 0;
                document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
            }
```

But it just doesn't work!! It works just fine with the script all in the HTML file, but not when linked to as separate .js. Any help welcome.

Comment: make sure to add script tag AFTER the html stuff just in case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet of your code, comments have been added where necessary. Run it to see the code in action.

```js
//Get the button
            var mybutton = document.getElementById("TopBtn");
            
            //Declare body and html as vars
            //Some browsers apply scroll to body, and others apply scroll to html so we are getting both
            var body = document.body
            var html = document.documentElement;

            // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top, show the button
            window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

            function scrollFunction() {
                if ( body.scrollTop || html.scrollTop > 20) {
                mybutton.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                mybutton.style.display = "none";
}
            }

          // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top
            function topFunction() {
                body.scrollTop = 0;
                html.scrollTop = 0;
            }
```

```css
#TopBtn {
display: none; 
position: fixed;
bottom: 1.25em;
right: 1.5em;
z-index: 99;font-size: 1em;
border: none;
outline: none;
background-color: #555;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 1em;
border-radius: .5em;
opacity: 0.5;
}

#TopBtn:hover {
background-color: #555;
opacity: 1;
}

  
body {  
  height: 2000px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  }
```

```html
<div onscroll="scrollFunction();">
Scroll the page
</div>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="TopBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

Additionally, in your coding environment, you can import scripts into your HTML file in a format similar to the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<head>
<!-- import additional CSS along with other meta data, etc.. in the head -->
<link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Everything else that makes the body of your document can go within the body tags -->
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="TopBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your suggestion but it only seems to work for a fixed size "container" and not for the whole page.

Comment: I've updated my code for you with additional comments. It will now work without a fixed container. - If this has solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct so it will help others and account for the time I've spent to answer. Happy coding!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Kindly mark the answer correct since it solved your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just figured out how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get your button by ID before the button exists in the page. As you're loading your script before your button.

Couple of options:

- Move your script to the bottom of the page just before closing `<html>` tag
- Add `defer` to your script tag inside your HTML
- Put your `getElementByID` call inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event.

An example of option 3:

```js
var mybutton; // declare variable outside the callback to keep in the global scope.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    mybutton = document.getElementById("TopBtn");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have moved the script as suggested and tried option 3, but to no effect.